# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/proc/bus/usb/’: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, usb, windows, vmware, suse

So, the error in the title.  Im having this issue where I cannot create this directory.

```
cstayner@SuSELaptop:~> sudo mkdir -p /proc/bus/usb/
[sudo] password for root: 
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/proc/bus/usb/’: No such file or directory
```

It says that there is no such file or directory.  Well, duh, that is why I am trying to create it.

Ive done some other research and I always see it suggested that this happens because the parent directory doesnt exist.  However, as you can see, it does:

```
cstayner@SuSELaptop:~> cd /proc/bus/
cstayner@SuSELaptop:/proc/bus> ls -l
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Feb 13 07:25 input
dr-xr-xr-x 6 root root 0 Feb 13 07:25 pci
cstayner@SuSELaptop:/proc/bus>
```

The point of creating the USB directory is I am running a Windows 10 x64 guest with VMware Workstation 15.5 on my SuSE Enterprise Desktop which is the latest version.  Im trying to use a USB flash drive within the guest.  VMware, however, doesnt even give USB devices as an option under removable devices.

Through some other research, I read that it looks at the /proc/bus/usb/ directory for USB devices.

So first question is, why is it rejecting making the directory?  Ive event tried creating it as root.  No difference.

Second question is, what can I do to make VMware see that there are USB devices there?  Yes, there is a USB controller added to the VM.

EDIT:

Host OS can see and use the USB devices without issue.  It is VMware that is not able to see the USB devices, and this is the same no matter which VM I use.  I have a Windows one and several different distros of Linux in VMs.  None of them have access to USB.

Comment: You cannot create directories in `/proc`, which is a virtual filesystem that exposes an interface of the kernel.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply.  That would explain that.  I see that even when I have a USB device attached, a USB directory doesnt appear here.  Is that a reason for VMware not seeing any USB devices attached?

Comment: Are you sure that vmware is looking into `/proc/bus/usb` and not `/dev/bus/usb`? usbfs has been deprecated a long, long time ago. Maybe it's because of permissions that vmware cannot pass through usb devices from the host to the guest.

Comment: @mosvy No, I am not.  I know that older versions did, but I dont know about newer versions.  I had been wondering if it was a permissions issue, but I wouldnt know how to check or change permissions if that is the case.  Im fairly new to the inner workings of Linux.  Ive used it as an OS for a while without digging too deep into it.

Comment: Is the `/proc` in the host or the guest? Does the host see the usb?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor It is in the host.  Host is SuSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 15 x64.  Guest is Windows 10 x64.  Host sees the drive just fine.  No issues there.

Comment: I am confused. You say it is in the host, [where the usb is not visible] ... Host sees the drive just fine. No issues there. Or was all the `/proc` stuff a Red herring. Please explain, by editing the question to make it clear.

Comment: `/proc/bus/usb` i believe is deprecated: https://askubuntu.com/questions/326597/enabling-usbfs-in-ubuntu

Comment: might have been replaced by `/sys/kernel/debug/usb`; need to check with your linux distribution and version you are using.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/35004

Comment: Okay, so problem fixed.  Through a bit more research, I landed on a page talking about similar issues with VMware on Arch Linux.  Looking through the suggested docs for arch linux, I was able to use the same method for fixing my issue.  This page helped me through all my issues: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware

Apparantly, it was all due to the usb-arbitrator service not running.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ man proc
```

will answer your first question.

> The proc filesystem is a pseudo-filesystem which provides an interface to kernel data structures.
>   It is commonly mounted at /proc.
>   Most of it is read-only, but some files allow kernel variables to be changed.

Sure you don't mean /sys/bus/usb/ ??

Comment: Yes, as I read, VMware looks under /proc/bus/usb/ for USB devices.  However, that could have been for an older version.  I dont know what Workstation 15.5 does as I couldnt really find anything on it.  Is what you mentioned where it would look>?

Comment: I'm not into VWware. but since /sys/ is where those devices show up I would guess that this is where VMware should look for them. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

I have no idea for VM-ware it is proprietary, so I don't use it.

However for Virtual-box, there is an option to share folders. This is preferred over giving the guest the USB device. There is also the option of handing over USB devices to the guest.